# How can I print a buffer exactly as it looks on the screen?

Tags: print, variable-pitch, htmlfontify, htmlize

How can I print a buffer exactly as it looks on screen, including the use of variable-pitch fonts?

(I'm also curious why `htmlfontify-buffer` ignores `variable-pitch-mode`.)

I am using `org-mode` and use variable-pitch fonts.  However, the latter are ignored when I generate HTML for printing via `htmlfontify-buffer`.  Is there a work around?

Also tried `htmlize`, but that was even worse usually not including any special fonts.

Comment: Have you tried adding links to a custom css? I usually export html to file and then print from web browser for best results.

Comment: Haven't tried custom css.  However, even having a simple file test.org with two lines and nothing fancy, and running htmlfontify-buffer generates an html file with the correct fonts but then the content is set inside <pre> tags, so the font information is ignored...

Comment: After reading about htmlfontify again, I think I understand. It may be treating the entire buffer as code which is why it wraps text in pre tags. I’m not sure if this will help but take a look at [org-html-themes](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes) and [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/). I’ve used both to export or convert org files into nice looking documents.